# Rewrite the word "website" to "web" on the URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

How can we replace the word `website` in our URLs to the word `web` through an `.htaccess` rewrite?

Example #1:

```
www.website.com/responsive-***website***-design
```

Need it to Redirect to:

```
www.website.com/responsive-***web***-design
```

Example #2(Website isn't always the second word):

```
www.website.com/high-end-***website***-design
```

Need it to Redirect to:

```
www.website.com/high-end-***web***-design
```

Answer (score 0):

If 'website' is always surrounded by hyphens, you could use this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)-website-(.*)$ /$1-web-$2 [R=302,NC,L]
```

Comment: you don't even need the hyphens and you will need the NC flag if the person type it as WEBsite it would not catch it as it is.

Comment: Ok, nice comment, thanks @Prix. The hyphens try to match the pretty-url defined at the end and do not replace something like /website/responsive-website-design to /web/responsive-web-design. I would not use NC in this case, but it could be a good idea. Let's Daniel Garibay decide on that, he knows what is server does

Comment: True in that case the hyphen would work however if any of the letters on website is in upper case the rule won't work which is why the NO CASE `NC` flag comes in as a good thing.

Comment: Ok, NC will make the rule work on most cases and make answer better. I have just edit the answer. Thanks again @Prix